# Subquery with joins - need help returning rows even if empty - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

okay guys, this is a big one that’s confusing as hell.

I’m creating a forum type dealio: I have an array of Topics and each topic has an array of Posts associated with the Topic. The Topics list page should show the latest Post from that specific Topic. (Each topic is in a category as well)

`Topic                      Latest post`
`Check out my page          John Smith - 10:00 PM`

```sql
MYSQL
select `ct`.*, `a`.`username`, `x`.* from `community-topics` as `ct` 
inner join `community-categories` as `cc` on `cc`.`communityCategoryId` = `ct`.`refCategoryId` 
inner join `authentication` as `a` on `a`.`userId` = `ct`.`refCreatedBy` 
inner join (
    select `a2`.`username` AS lastPostUsername, `cp`.`createdAt` AS lastPostCreatedAt, 
    `cp`.`body`, `cp`.`refTopicId` from `community-posts` as `cp` 
    inner join `authentication` as `a2` on `a2`.`userId` = `cp`.`refCreatedBy`
    order by `cp`.`createdAt` desc limit 1
) as x on `x`.`refTopicId` = `ct`.`communityTopicId`
where `cc`.`name` = 'general' order by `ct`.`createdAt` desc
```

This query actually works how I need it to. The only issue is that a row won’t return if the subquery is empty. I still want to return all of the data outside of the subquery even if the subquery is null / false / empty. I've tried using IFNULL / ISNULL, but I don't think I'm using it right with the additional joins in the subquery.

if I have 2 topics, 1 topic with 5 posts, 1 topic with 0 posts, only the topic with 5 posts will show up and the topic with 0 posts won’t show up because the subquery returns empty.

If the row is empty, I’d like to return something to the front end user showing something like “Sorry, no recent posts” or something along those lines.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please don't edit questions if it invalidates reasonable posted answers, ask a new question. I rolled this back. Please accept the answer if it helped you. Although the question isn't very clear. You can roll back my rollback, but please research how to ask. [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: `t join (...t.c...) u` is called a lateral join & DBMSs can require & may or may not support use of keyword LATERAL. PS You don't clearly say how output is supposed to be a function of inputs. You contradictorily follow "actually works how I need it to" with "only issue is". Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. When pared down this will be a faq.

Comment: @philipxy the edit doesn't invalidate the answer, it actually clarifies that the answer given doesn't quite answer it completely. The edit is also reformatted for MRE, as you said, which you reverted. Regardless, lateral is the right direction I was looking for. Fortunately I'm using MySQL 8, otherwise lateral wouldn't work, FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join` if you want to keep rows even when there is no match:

```
select `ct`.*, `a`.`username`, `x`.*
from `community-topics` `ct` inner join
     `community-categories` `cc`
      on `cc`.`communityCategoryId` = `ct`.`refCategoryId` inner join 
      `authentication` `a`
      on `a`.`userId` = `ct`.`refCreatedBy` left join
      (select `a2`.`username` AS lastPostUsername, `cp`.`createdAt` AS lastPostCreatedAt, 
             `cp`.`body`, `cp`.`refTopicId`
       from `community-posts` as `cp` left join
            `authentication` as `a2`
             on `a2`.`userId` = `cp`.`refCreatedBy`
       order by `cp`.`createdAt` desc limit 1
      )  x
      on `x`.`refTopicId` = `ct`.`communityTopicId`
where `cc`.`name` = 'general'
order by `ct`.`createdAt` desc;
```

I would also recommend that you remove all the backticks.  They just make the query harder to write and to read.

EDIT:

If I understand your comment:

```
select `ct`.*, `a`.`username`, `x`.*
from `community-topics` `ct` inner join
     `community-categories` `cc`
      on `cc`.`communityCategoryId` = `ct`.`refCategoryId` inner join 
      `authentication` `a`
      on `a`.`userId` = `ct`.`refCreatedBy` left join
      (select `a2`.`username` AS lastPostUsername, `cp`.`createdAt` AS lastPostCreatedAt, 
             `cp`.`body`, `cp`.`refTopicId`,
             row_number() over (partition by refTopicId order by cp.created_at desc) as seqnum
       from `community-posts` as `cp` left join
            `authentication` as `a2`
             on `a2`.`userId` = `cp`.`refCreatedBy`
      )  x
      on `x`.`refTopicId` = `ct`.`communityTopicId` and seqnum = 1
where `cc`.`name` = 'general'
order by `ct`.`createdAt` desc;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon. I took your advice and removed all the backticks - waaayyy cleaner.  The query works pretty well - only issue is that the subquery is only returning the last “post” for one “topic”, not the last “post” for ALL “topics”.

Essentially I think I need a WHERE cp.refTopicId = ct.communityTopicId in the subquery, but I get the error: Unknown column 'ct.communityTopicId' in 'where clause’, since the ct table is only referenced in the main/outer query. The post has been updated.